# Privileges/Rights applied to group at the global level are not being applied to the queue level

Tags: rt

I have created my own group of users in RT.

What I don't understand is why privileges and rights that I give to this group do not apply at the group level. Is it really necessary to add the group to each queue and then assign the privileges? This would be very tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is necessary to add the group to each queue and define the privileges.

The privileges shown in the Global rights are different from those available at the queue level.
You can configure privileges for Roles like Requestor and Owner which would be applicable to all queues.